# Alexa Just Listen Invocation name and than blinks and stop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Alexa just Listen The invocation name and blinks And Stop. After  4-5 try it starts the skill i checked the cloudwatch for log and it prints this :-

**Error has occured Error: read ECONNRESET**
What Does this mean and how can i solve thhis >? i have Written Code in node.js on aws lambda

Answer (score 1):

Error: read ECONNRESET is the primary cause and says that your connection/request got cancelled on the TCP/IP level. This may have many reasons but basically your request is configured correctly. It might just be the server you are sending the requests to which is resetting the connection. All you can do then is retrying the request.